# Use Ansible Special Variables in Playbook Vars Section

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a conditional variable - if the `ansible_user` is `ansible` then I will set the `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` so it doesn't need to be specified on the command line. I have previously used `ansible_user` within my playbooks, but it appears it doesn't work within the `vars` section:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    private_key_file: "~/.ssh/ansible/ansible_ed25519"
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ private_key_file if ansible_user == 'ansible' else '' }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}"
```

I can reference `inventory_hostname` in the `vars` section without a problem, but it doesn't like `ansible_user` as it results in the following error when running `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts.yml -u ansible -k`:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'private_key_file' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_user' is undefined. 'ansible_user' is undefined. 'ansible_user' is undefined. 'ansible_user' is undefined"}
```

I am able to query `ansible_user` in a task further down - anyone know of an alternative to get the `-u <user>` value from the command line to use in `vars`?

I have verified that `ansible_user` is visible within the playbook, e.g:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: "ansible_user"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_user }}"
```

If I then run this play I get the following:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts.yml -u ansible -k

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible_user] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [icct0-s1-aob-01] => {
    "msg": "ansible"
}
```

This proves I do have a valid value for `ansible_user`, but I just can't reference it from within `vars`.

Comment: Since the `vars` keyword is usable at multiple levels, could you confirm that you are speaking about the `vars` section of a playbook?

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve].

Comment: Updated the question to include some more context

Comment: I cannot reproduce if I do pass the `-u some`

Comment: If you are not, on the other end, then this is your explanation: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/23530#issuecomment-293991147

Comment: Updated the example so it does fail.. well.. does for me every time (`ansible-core==2.15.0`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting the ansible user on the command line with `-u`, the `ansible_user` variable won't be available as a fact in the header of your play. You can work around this by:

1. Setting `ansible_user` in your inventory instead of on the command line, or
2. Effectively promoting it to a "real fact" like this:

   ```
   - hosts: all
     gather_facts: false
     tasks:
       - set_fact:
           ansible_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"

   - hosts: all

     vars:
       private_key_file: "~/.ssh/ansible/ansible_ed25519"
       ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ private_key_file if ansible_user == 'ansible' else '' }}"

     tasks:
       - debug:
           msg: "{{ ansible_ssh_private_key_file }}"
   ```

Comment: I've updated this answer with two potential workarounds for your current situation.